# Modifying First and Last Name in Hotmail via script

Tags: http, scripting, request, hotmail

I would like to write a script that logs into hotmail and changes the first and last name. I am thinking of perl for this, although I imagine that any language would do.

How do I find out what requests to make? I'm guessing that I can do the change requests manually, determine what http requests are being sent to/from the server, determine what pattern is being sent, and then attempt to generate a similar pattern (substituting in the changes I want) in my script.

I took a look at ethereal, but I get a message "the installer is corrupted". I'm going to look at "Advanced http packet sniffer" next - anyone have experience with this tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Perl (or any languages with modules that support HTTP(S) ). And you can use libraries already made by people. Eg [WWW::Hotmail](http://search.cpan.org/~xantus/WWW-Hotmail-0.10/Hotmail.pm)  or [Hotwayd](http://freshmeat.net/projects/hotwayd/). Search CPAN for more of those modules as well.

Comment: Thanks, now how do I track the requests that are being made from my browser to the server each time I e.g. submit a change by hitting a "save" button? I know this is probably elementary but I have to start somewhere :)